# dependent samples & correction for multiple testing

Tags: multiple-comparisons, independence, bioinformatics

I have situation in which I compare many genomic regions between two or more cell lines (CL). Each region is covered by n probes measuring the level of methylation (continuous variable). The coverage (value of n = sample size per region, generally varies between 4 and 20) is different for different regions (array property, property of the base pair sequence) . However, for 1 region n is the same for all CLs.

For example (n=2, A & B)

region 1 has 5 measurements in each cell line.

```
region 1, CL A: 23  9   80  62  31

region 1, CL B: -98 -65 -19 -95 -23
```

region 2 has 10 measurements within the region (bigger region and/or better coverage)

```
region 2, CL A: 66  7   31  89  100 81  63  93  33  0

region 2, CL B: 17  -50 -89 -46 -52 -80 -7  -26 -62 -26
```

The data has one additional property: the measurements WITHIN one cell line & region are correlated, e.g. if one of the measurements (one genomic locus) gives a high methylation value, the adjacent locus is more probable to also be high. I have illustrated this by the sign of the numbers in the demo data. (There is no repeated measurement involved.)

The number of regions of interest concerns several thousand regions.

I want to do 2 things

1. Test for each region whether A differs from B. Currently I use a Mann
   Whitney U test for this if n=2 (A,B) or Kruskal Wallis if n>2
   (A,B,C,...) . I have been told that because of the correlation, the
   assumption of independence of the measurements (=samples) fails and
   I should use a permutation test. Is the approach as implemented in
   the "coin" package in R
   (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/vignettes/coin.pdf)
   applicable to this problem (conditional counterpart of unconditional
   tests).
2. Correct for multiple testing. As my sample sizes vary between the
   regions I am at a loss here. The p-values do not seem to be
   comparable because of this, so application of default FWER based correction might not be possible, right?

I would very much appreciate any insight. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't simply use the mean of all measurements for a region within a cell line as the methylation measure for that region in the cell line? That at least removes the issue of correlation of readings within a region/cell line. Also, overall region methylation within a cell line may be more informative biologically than the collection of 2 to 20 different measurements. Then you're simply faced with the same issues of multiple testing dealt with for years in microarray analyses among cell lines.

Comment: Dear EdM,
Thanks for your reply. Taking the mean for each region will give me an idea about that region's methylation status, but it will not tell me if a specific region is differentially methylated between the two cell lines. For that I need to test each region separately.
The issue about "global" methylation that you address is also an interesting question, but here I am specifically interested in specific regulatory regions. This because differences in methylation for specific regions might indicate differential biological regulation of genes between the samples.
Thanks. Martin